# See what methods/events being called in JS

Tags: javascript, debugging, events, logging

Got this page which has some javascript on it (very heavy) and I am trying to see what happens when I click a certain element. However looking at the code there is no onclick function - the javascript is several JS files so take far to long to browse.

Is there a way with Firefox (firebug), Chrome or even IE to view whats / log what is happening when I click on an element in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox (and this is also available in chrome and IE in another form) install addon firebug (if not installed). Go to Tools->Birebug->Open Firebug. Click on Left Icon and ask for tracing.
You can then trace your program.
Another way is to cause a breakpoint when you start, and you manually follow the execution of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Developer Tools shows all attached event handlers for an element. See the section on [Event Listeners](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/elements.html) towards the end.

[image: Event Listeners in Chrome Developer Tools]

Answer (score 0):

@wizzard, try this: firebug - profiling button
ff only, but there is a [lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/) version for chrome for example